# Is it valid to change the classification criteria of a model after it's been created?

Tags: classification, chemometrics

(Please note, I'm a chemist with some minor experience with ML, nothing formal)

[I am reading this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acscentsci.0c00229) that is using a DNN to predict (via classification) if a certain molecule has a good score when a calculation ('docking') is applied to it. 'Docking' is an expensive calculation because the amount of potential molecules to dock is very large (>1 billion), not because 'docking' one molecule is expensive.

The paper begins with a straight forward approach. They dock 3M molecules from a large database (>1B) and use that to make a 'training', 'test', and 'validation' set. Each set contains 1M molecules.

They would like to predict whether a 'docking score' (negative values are good in docking) is below a certain threshold in order to be classified as a 'hit' (a good result). They use the top 1% of docking score from their validation set in order to set a cut off that the model can use to classify.

Now that they have a model, they predict over the whole database and dock 1M of the predicted hits. They use these results to update the model.

So far this all makes sense to me. They then want to continue iterating this process. However, they mention this in their methods:

"From the second iteration onward, the training set was expanded with 1 million molecules randomly sampled from hits predicted in the previous iteration, while validation and test sets remained unchanged for all the length of the DD run. The score cutoff was gradually decreased (corresponding to higher predicted target affinity) after each iteration to keep selecting better compounds. This reduction was done by linearly lowering the percentage of top scoring molecules in the validation set assigned to the virtual hit class from 1% in the first iteration to 0.01% in the last one."

Something here feels off to me, how can you update a model if the goal of the model changes? Wouldn't each iteration be an entirely new model? Is this difference purely pedantic? Would this be considered active learning?